# Limit on size of Apache Ignite value stored using Memcache protocol

Tags: memcached, ignite

When using the Memcached protocol to connect to Apache Ignite, any value greater than 16384 characters in length will save incorrectly. When you attempt to retrieve this data it will appear 'garbled'. But any string 16384 or less will save and retrieve correctly.

We have tried a number of Ignite configurations, including the one specified here: http://apacheignite.gridgain.org/v1.1/docs/php

This same issue happens when using both the PHP and Java Memcached libraries. And both work perfectly fine with values less than 16385 characters in length.

Comment: What do you want the outcome to be if its greater than 16385 in length?

Comment: I would like it to be retrievable exactly as it was inputted. Currently it is appearing entirely different. To note this was also added to the Ignite Forum and is picked up as a Jira ticket. http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Limit-on-size-of-Apache-Ignite-value-stored-using-Memcache-protocol-td7279.html

Answer (score 0):

Ignite JIRA ticket for this issue is created: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3772